# How to generate partial checksum of a file

Tags: linux, hash, md5

How can i calculate, let's say md5 sum of first 1024 bytes of a file?

I tried `od -N 1024 | md5sum` however od output is in octal format by default and this generates different md5 hash.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`head -c 1024 | md5sum`

should work.

Full example, as requested in comments:

`head -c 1024 your_file | md5sum`

Comment: please always state a full example (eg specify file)

Answer (score 9):

Suppose a more complicated case:
You need to get your 2nd 1GB part of your first partition. use dd command:

```
dd bs=1M skip=1024 count=1024 if=/dev/sda1 | md5sum
```

Note that we haven't used `of=` part of `dd` command. So its output will be redirected to standard output, that we piped to the next command.

Comment: Add `status=noxfer` not to add the transfer stats like `1+0 ...` to the sum input.

Comment: It doesn't look like `status` affects the inputs to the md5sum.  Tried it with `status=none`, `status=noxfer`, `status=progress`, and without `status`.  Got different information printed to the screen, but the md5 sum was the same.